# How to find path to a field in a graphql query

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, gql, gqlquery

I am very new to graphql. I have a following graphql query for an example:

```
query pets {
  breed(some arguments) 
  {
    name
    items 
    {
      owner(some arguments) 
      {
        items 
        {
          ID
          ownerSnumber
          country
          address
          school
          nationality
          gender
          activity
        }
      }
      name
      phoneNumber
      sin
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to **parse** a gql query and get the path of a field in the query?
For example I would like to get the path of '**ID**'. For example from the above query, is it possible to get the path where the `ID` is: `owner.items.ID`

Answer (score 1):

With https://graphql.org/graphql-js/ it exposes a fourth argument called **`resolve info`**. This field contains more information about the field.

Have a look at [GraphQLObjectType](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype) config parameter type definition:

Answer (score 0):

With a good start from the earlier answer, relying on the ResolveInfo you could do something like a recursive check going from child to parent:

```js
export const getFieldPath = (path: Path): string => {
  if (!path.prev) return `${path.key}`

  return `${getFieldPath(path.prev)}.${path.key}`
}
```

And later in your resolver you could use it like:

```js
const myFieldResolver = (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
  const pathOfThisResolversField = getFieldPath(info.path)

  // use your pathOfThisResolversField 

  return yourFieldResolvedData
};
```

Worth noting though, the solution above will include every node all the way to the query root, rather than just the ones you mentioned `owner.items.ID`